# Rails 4.2: Not rendering AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my first time using AJAX so with my objective in mind, I decided to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451758/rails-3-2-modal-popup-on-show-action) post for general guidance. I too would like a "modal popup on show action", the only difference is I'd like it render on my `new.html.erb` page rather than the `index` mentioned on the article.

In my `new.html.erb` I already have AJAX saving a record aka "Draft". After that there is a button that pops-up a modal. In this modal, I'd like to display the `show` action aka `get` the previously saved object - but I'm not seeing anything.

Not sure exactly what's going as this is a bit foreign to me. **Anyone know what I'm missing here?**

Here's what I have..

**controllers/campaigns_controller.rb**

```
      def show
        @campaign = Campaign.includes(:program, :uploadzip, :plan, :uploadpdfs).find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js 
            format.json { render json: @campaign }
        end
      end
```

**views/campaigns/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row title">
    <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
    <h2>Launch a Campaign</h2>
    </div>
</div>


<%= render 'form' %>

    <%= button_tag(type: "button", id: "campaign-create-button") do %>
        <% link_to "Confirm & Execute", @campaign, class: "link-button", action: "show", remote: true %>
    <% end %>
```

**views/campaigns/_target.html.erb** *(A Zurb-Foundation's modal)*

```
<div id="executeModal" class="row large " role="dialog">

  <div class="large-12 columns modal-header" id="modal-prompt">
      <h3 class="row">Warning: Confirm Campaign</h3>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>You are about to execute a campaign. Please confirm campaign settings one last time before executing.</p>
      </div>


           <div class="row">

              <div id="campaignModal">
              </div>

            <div class="row">
            <%= button_tag "Cancel", type: "button", class: "cancelButton confirmButton" %>

            <%= button_tag "Execute Campaign", type: "button", class: "confirmButton" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**views/campaigns/show.js.erb**

```
$modal = $('#executeModal');
$modalBody = $('#campaignModal');
$modalBody.html("<%= escape_javascript(render @campaign) %>");
$modal.modal();
```

**views/campaigns/_campaign.html.erb**

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Campaign Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                <%= @campaign.name %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Program:
                </td>
                <td>
                 <%= @campaign.program.name %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Zip File:
                </td>
                <td>
                <%= @campaign.uploadzip.file_name %> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Additional Files:
                </td>
                <td>
                <% @campaign.uploadpdfs.each do |f| %>
                    <li><%= f.file_name %></li>
                <% end %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Plan:
                </td>
                <td>
                <%= @campaign.plan.name %> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Channels:
                </td>
                <td>
                <%= @campaign.channels.to_sentence %>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**UPDATE:**

Incase the way I have the form saving the object is somehow interfering or not setup correctly, below is the code for that.

```
$(".close-button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var planId = $("#campaign_plan_id").val();
    var nameId = $("#campaign_name").val();
    var programId = $("#campaign_program_id").val();
    var uploadZip = $("#uploadzip_id").val();
    // var uploadPdf = $("campaign[uploadpdf_ids][]").val();

    if (planId.length > 0 && 
        nameId.length > 0 && 
        programId.length > 0 && 
        uploadZip.length > 0){
        $('form#new_campaign').trigger('submit.rails');
        $("#targetModal, .modalDarken").fadeOut();
        $("#target-button").hide();
        $("#campaign-create-button").css("display", "block").css("background-color", "#E37368");
    } else {
        $("#targetModal, .modalDarken").fadeOut();

    }

});
```

Comment: For one, I don't see class `executeModal` anywhere although you have an id with that name.  If you want to access that in your .js.erb, it should be `#executeModal` (not `.executeModal`).

Comment: Also, just like in the post you site, you will need a place in your modal where you can insert your campaign.  I don't see where you are doing that, unless it is the div that includes the buttons (which would then get overwritten by the @campaign).

Comment: @steveklein - 
Thanks for catching the class/id mixup. I fixed those and edited my post above to reflect it. I add a `div` with the `id="campaignModal"` to specify where the content show go. Am I suppose to render the partial myself or is that done with js code I have above? With the changes, I'm still not seeing anything. I tried rendering using `<%= render "target" %>` but got `undefined method name for @campaign.providers.name`

Comment: I would change `$modalBody = $('#executeModal #campaignModal')` to `$modalBody = $('#campaignModal')` and I'm hoping this line and the one before it is terminated by a semicolon, not a comma (better to copy/paste code in here to avoid typos).  At this point, I would run a debugger to see what `@campaign` is set to in your .js.erb.

Comment: @steveklein - Lines are terminated by semicolon ;). I updated the change above. I did throw the debugger around and found that `@campaign` isn't being set! Also, the html table tags are not even showing up when I put the debugger in the `_campaign.html.erb` partial. So I still can't get the partial to display. I aslo added `action: "show"` on my button in hopes that would help - but it's a no go.

Comment: At this point, I would confirm overall flow - make sure controller action is invoked as expected, then make sure .js.erb is executed, when the button is clicked.

Comment: @steveklein - I'm finding that it is making a request to my `index` even though I specified for `show`. Is my button params look correct to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81577/discussion-between-steve-klein-and-shroy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for posterity... we sorted a bunch of syntax issues but didn't realize until we were close to "finished" that the AJAX remote call was being triggered off of the New view, yet expected a created instance to "show" through AJAX.  So that won't work... in the SO post referenced in the OP here, the call was originated on the Index view, which makes more sense.

btw, that [SO reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451758/rails-3-2-modal-popup-on-show-action?answertab=active#tab-top) looks quite good.