# rails: creating modal pop up window from another view page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dashboard page where I'm displaying some images and name:

**views/dashboard/index.html.haml**

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = link_to item do
    = image_tag item.images.try(:first).try(:url,:medium)
    = item.name
```

Then I have this separate page:

**views/items/_quick_view.html.haml**

Where I want to display the correct content based on the click from the dashboard page. I want to make this a modal window, so when someone clicks on an item, it'll have more information within this quick view page. Not sure if this is even the correct way to do it? In addition, how would I pass the information along to the quick view page so it knows which correct content to appear?

Do I add some kind of rendering like this?

```
- @items.each do |item|
  = link_to item do
    = image_tag item.images.try(:first).try(:url,:medium)
    = item.name
  .modal{style: 'display:none;'}
    = render '/items/quick_view.html.haml', :item => item
```

I have no idea how this would work. Need some direction on this please.

Answer (score 0):

If you did like you suggested, would be necessary to link each item link with the related modal. Like `link_to item` would have to generate something like `<a href='#modal1'>...</a>` and for every item it would render a modal with the appropriate ID('#modal1', '#modal2'). It's possible but would be a lot(one modal per item) of html if your page gets bigger.

The other solution is to make the load dynamically and have only one modal(#detail_view) and any click on the item would make a AJAX call to some route and controller action that would respond to a remote call answering with the content for the modal. Injecting this content inside your '#detail_view' modal.

To implement the second solution I suggest look this [another SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451758/rails-3-2-modal-popup-on-show-action). It's a solution for the show view, but you could have a similar action creating a route for a detail_view action and return a @item object. It's pretty well explained there.